# Moving items between tables using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four tables of soccer players, one for goalkeepers, one for defenders, one for midfielders and one for attackers. I want the user to be able to change the position of a player so that he'll disappear from his current table and appear in another one without a page refresh.

The only method that I can think of is to have each player listed in all four tables but have him hidden for three of them. Then if he changes, I hide him in the current table and show him in another one.

I know how to achieve this, but it seems a bit heavy and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: You could simply [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the row to the other table.

Comment: Could .detach() work here? This would allow you detach the DOM element and then re-insert it wherever necessary.  https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: Ah thanks guys, I'll look into these. My method sounds like far too much HTML.

Comment: yes...moving rows from one place to another is not uncommon or difficult

Comment: I've added a snippet to my answer to demonstrate how you can use `appendChild()`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes Michael, thank you very much. I haven't used these commands before so example code is extremely useful :)

Comment: Then would you mind accepting my answer, please? There's a checkmark next to my answer that you can click.

Comment: Ah yes, did that, thought I had to click the up arrow and I don't have enough rep. But ticked it now, it's the most complete answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `appendChild()` in pure JavaScript to move a node from one place to another. The node is automatically removed from its old position in the DOM.

To quote the Mozilla Developer Network [documentation on `appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).
>
> This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, it is first removed, then appended at the new position.

The following snippet demonstrates the use of `appendChild()` to move rows between tables. Click on the `move` buttons to move an item from one table to the other.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var data = {
    like: ['vanilla', 'pistachio', 'squirrels', 'squash', 'mountains'],
    dislike: ['chocolate', 'trucks', 'football', 'hard candy', 'valleys']
  };
  var tables = {};
  var moveMe = function () {
    this.table = tables[this.table === tables.like ? 'dislike' : 'like'];
    this.table.tbody.appendChild(this.tr);
  };
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    var container = document.createElement('div'),
        table = tables[key] = document.createElement('table'),
        tbody = table.tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    data[key].forEach(function (item) {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr'),
          td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = item;
      tr.appendChild(td);
      tbody.appendChild(tr);
      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerHTML = 'move';
      button.onclick = moveMe;
      button.table = table;
      button.tr = tr;
      td.appendChild(button);
    });
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    var header = document.createElement('h2');
    header.innerHTML = key;
    container.appendChild(header);
    container.appendChild(table);
    container.className = 'container';
    document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(container);
  });
};
```

```css
* {
  box-model: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 450px;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: #666;
}
table {
  width: 200px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  position: relative;
}
td button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
td button:hover {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [table api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) to manipulate your tables, here is a sample:

moving 1,1,1 element to 3,1,1

```js
var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table")
var elementToMove = tables[0].rows[0].cells[0]
var destination = tables[2].rows[0].cells[0]

destination.innerHTML = elementToMove.innerHTML
elementToMove.innerHTML = ""
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1,1,1</td>
    <td>1,1,2</td>
    <td>1,1,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1,2,1</td>
    <td>1,2,2</td>
    <td>1,2,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1,3,1</td>
    <td>1,3,2</td>
    <td>1,3,3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2,1,1</td>
    <td>2,1,2</td>
    <td>2,1,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2,2,1</td>
    <td>2,2,2</td>
    <td>2,2,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2,3,1</td>
    <td>2,3,2</td>
    <td>2,3,3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>3,1,1</td>
    <td>3,1,2</td>
    <td>3,1,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3,2,1</td>
    <td>3,2,2</td>
    <td>3,2,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3,3,1</td>
    <td>3,3,2</td>
    <td>3,3,3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that i'm using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to access data, but you could identify whatever element you have in the cell and then use the [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method to move the element you need